# How does one force a <button> tag to display:inline?

Tags: button, css

Check this out:

http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/vGKBr

Now, they look fine when you aren't hovering over them, but when you hover over the `<button>` and `<input>` elements, you'll see that the text below them is bumped around a bit, while hovering over the `<a>` element does not cause the same effect. That's because the `<button>` and `<input>` elements are displaying as `inline-block`s still (which handle borders, padding, and margins differently than regular `inline`s), despite the `display: inline !important;` line that is applied to them.

Is there anyway to override this? I know it's doable via hacks like borders with the same colour as the background, etc. but I'd really like to know if there's a way to make them `display: inline` properly.

Note: The problem here isn't about the text being bumped around (though that is an effect of it), it's that, despite everything saying otherwise, the browser is still forcing the button to display as an `inline-block`. Thanks to everyone who's provided methods to prevent the text bumping from happening, but that's not the real problem here.

Thanks!

Comment: Those elements are *already* laid inline by default, so declaring `display: inline` in your CSS won't actually change anything. As for why they behave the way they do with a border... I dunno.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in FF and Chrome at least, those elements aren't laid inline, they're laid as inline-blocks. One of the differences those create is the difference in how they handle borders, as you can see in the difference between the button elements and the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the context of why your markup exists like this, but the issue looks like it's being triggered by setting the font-family. If you take a look at this pen - http://codepen.io/pnts/pen/Egwuo - the hover works fine without a font-family specified, but if you uncomment the line specifying one, the jumping begins.

Comment: +10 points for creativity, but that's just because of the line height differences between the two different typefaces. If you open up inspector on those buttons, you'll see that they're still both displaying as `inline-block`s.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is a little misleading. Your button tag IS in fact set to display:inline on both normal and hover states. It sounds like the question you have is how to prevent the text below from getting bumped down on rollover. Instead of using a bottom border as you are currently, why not use the following in the hover state to achieve the underline?

```
text-decoration:underline;
```

Comment: Made the same comment above, but I'll post again here for clarity.

Thanks for the response, but in FF and Chrome at least, those elements aren't laid inline, they're laid as inline-blocks. One of the differences between those is how they handle borders, as you can see in the difference between hovering over the button elements and the <a> element in my demo.

I don't want to use underline because that's not the effect I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

agree with the previous answer, however if you want the flexibility of a border, being able to use padding to adjust where it lays etc, you could use

```
border:1px solid transparent;
```

not as hacky as using the same color as you bg because it doesn't matter the color of the background that way.

Comment: That's still hacky in a way I'm not looking for. The problem could easily be solved if I could get the `<button>` elements to display as inline instead of inline-block. (Read comments on other posts for more on that)